# py2cytoscape - automate saving view

Tags: python-3.x, cytoscape

I want to automate saving a view in cytoscape using the `py2cytoscape` package.

```
from py2cytoscape import cyrest

cytoscape = cyrest.cyclient()
cytoscape.network.load_file("FILENAME.cyjs")
cytoscape.vizmap.apply(styles="default")
cytoscape.network.set_current(network="FILENAME")
cytoscape.layout.apply_preferred()
cytoscape.view.set_current(network="FILENAME")
cytoscape.view.fit_content()
cytoscape.network.deselect(nodeList='all', edgeList='all')

cytoscape.view.export(options="PDF", OutputFile="FILENAME")
```

Output below:

```
ValueError: {'status': 500, 'type': 'urn:cytoscape:ci:cyrest-core:v1:handle-json-command:errors:2', 'message': 'java.lang.NullPointerException', 'link': 'file:/Users/mgruzynski/CytoscapeConfiguration/3/framework-cytoscape.log'}
```

I tried to follow (Exporting high resolution image files):
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape-automation/blob/master/for-scripters/Python/advanced-cancer-networks-and-data.ipynb, but am getting the errors shown above.

Comment: Should edit your post with at least a detail question so we know what you are trying to ask help for.

Comment: As pointed out in the error, there might be more information in the log. Can you attach that?

Comment: this was fixed by just putting a time wait in so that cytoscape can catch up to the python code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer, but please consider writing this as an answer below and accepting it, so that people with the same problem can find the solution faster and more detailed (please remember to add the relevant code too).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There have been small changes with Cytoscape 3.7.1

Please install py2cytoscape from the development branch

```
pip uninstall py2cytoscape
pip install git+https://github.com/cytoscape/py2cytoscape.git --user
```

and then use

```
cytoscape.view.export(options="PDF", outputFile="FILENAME")
```